# Get the main storyboard at runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uistoryboard

I'd like to be able to simply call `[UIStoryboard mainStoryboard]` to get either the iPad or iPhone storyboard at runtime.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's a UIStoryboard category that'll do just this:

## UIStoryboard+LDMain.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIStoryboard (LDMain)

+ (instancetype)LDMainStoryboard;

@end
```

## UIStoryboard+LDMain.m

```
#import "UIStoryboard+LDMain.h"

UIStoryboard *_mainStoryboard = nil;

@implementation UIStoryboard (LDMain)

+ (instancetype)LDMainStoryboard {
    if (!_mainStoryboard) {
        NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
        NSString *storyboardName = [bundle objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"UIMainStoryboardFile"];
        _mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:bundle];
    }
    return _mainStoryboard;
}

@end
```

Here's a [link to the gist](https://gist.github.com/rcdilorenzo/6942398)

Comment: Categories on framework classes should always use prefixes to avoid name collisions.

Comment: Thanks. I've made the changes.

Comment: Cool; the method names are actually the more important part, though.

Comment: It's not really this simple. This will get you a copy of the main storyboard. If you do it repeatedly, you'll get new copies of the storyboard each time.

Comment: Well, mostly? If you already have the storyboard loaded via the regular application startup, you'll have two copies of it. Which is probably better than N copies. :)

Answer (score 13):

You can use `[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:bundle]` if the storyboard has not already been loaded.

If it has, though, this will load a new copy.

You can also use `viewController.storyboard` to get the existing one. If you have a `mainWindow` as part of your application delegate (you probably do), you can get the `rootViewController.storyboard` of that.

Something like:

```
UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
MyAppDelegate *myAppDelegate = ((MyAppDelegate *)application).delegate;
return myAppDelegate.mainWindow.rootViewController.storyboard;
```

If not, this might work for you:

```
UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
UIWindow *backWindow = application.windows[0];
return backWindow.rootViewController.storyboard
```